# MiniKube coredns is in CrashLoopBackOff status in AWS EC2

Tags: amazon-ec2, minikube, coredns

I am new to Minikube. We deployed minikube version: v1.0.1 on **AWS EC2**. `Coredns` is showing as `CrashLoopBackOff`.

```
kubectl get -n kube-system pods

NAME                               READY   STATUS             RESTARTS   AGE

coredns-6765558d84-6bpff           0/1     CrashLoopBackOff   531        44h
coredns-6765558d84-9mqz6           0/1     CrashLoopBackOff   531        44h
```

The logs of these pods are showing:

```
2019-05-22T06:29:40.959Z [FATAL] plugin/loop: Loop (127.0.0.1:53726 -> :53) detected for zone ".", see https://coredns.io/plugins/loop#troubleshooting. Query: "HINFO 1771143215983809104.2668792180170228628."
```

I did try to remove the word loop from a config file - as per another Stackoverflow ticket. CoreDNS started working, but proxy stopped!